# gfortran compilation error: FORM specifier in OPEN statement at (1) has invalid value 'print'

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran77

I am trying to compile an old Fortran 77 code (.f file) using GNU gfortran (configured with gcc 4.8.1) on a mac 10.8 and I am getting this error even on using -std=legacy flag.

```
gfortran -std=legacy -o grdsp96 grdsp96.f 

grdsp96.f:1872.72:

         open (1,file=dfile(i),access='append',form='print')            
                                                                        1
Error: FORM specifier in OPEN statement at (1) has invalid value 'print'
grdsp96.f:2052.72:

        open (1,file=dfile(i),status='unknown',form='print')            
                                                                        1
Error: FORM specifier in OPEN statement at (1) has invalid value 'print'
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

How to fix this ? Thanks.

Comment: That is a non-standard extension (if it ever worked), provided by a compiler.  Do you know which compiler was originally targeted?

Comment: sorry i don't know, i will send an email to the original author of the code and ask. it fails with both g77 and gfortran on my mac and also on an old linux machine.

Comment: A quick google on "open from='print'" gives https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/805-4939/c400000b796f/index.html might be useful. Basically I suspect you'll end up just cutting that part out of the open statement

Comment: when you delete the `form="print"` specifier, the main noticeable change you may see is where you have *list directed* writing of *strings* the default behavior likely will add an extra space in column 1.  If this is a problem, the best fix really is to fix your write statements to use string `(a)` formatting.